# Android - application crashes when trying to add item to database

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter, android-database

I am totally new to developing Android applications and I do not understand why my app crashes. Here's the code:

```
public class ProductListActivity extends ListActivity {

private ProductDataSource datasource;
private ListView lv;
private ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_list);
    this.addListenerOnAddNewProductButton();

    datasource = new ProductDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    datasource.deleteAllProducts();

    List<Product> values = datasource.getAllProducts();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Product>(
            this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            values );
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private void addListenerOnAddNewProductButton() {
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_new);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            EditText addProductInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_product_text);
            String newProductName = addProductInput.getText().toString();
            Product addedProduct = datasource.createProduct(newProductName);

            ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Product>) getListAdapter();
            adapter.add(addedProduct);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Product added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            addProductInput.setText("");
        }
    });
}
```

I do not understand why products are added to database and still I am receiving the error telling me I am trying to invoke a method on a null object.

Error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

I've already seen similar topic here on SO, but it didn't help me - as you can see, I declared my adapter as a global variable in this class. What's going on?

Comment: can we see your `getListAdapter()` method?

Comment: Actually, I didn't implement it. I am doing this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html#tutorial-using-sqlite

Comment: okay well I see removing that method worked for you, cause I was going to suggest that since `adapter` is an instance variable you could to without the method cause it's returning null.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [setListAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#setListAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)) method from `ListActivity` instead of using the one from `ListView`.

In onCreate, you can do:

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

instead of

```
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Indeed, it works.What's the difference between these two methods?

Comment: lv.setAdapter(adapter) sets the adapter in the ListView not the activity. getListAdapter gets the adapter from the activity, which in your case is null.

Comment: @TheOpti Since you have a `ListActivity`, you don't need references to `lv` or `adapter` in your class. You use `getListView()` and `getListAdapter()`, respectively

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Product>) getListAdapter();
```

instead of:

```
ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<Product>) getListAdapter();
```

and change:

```
private ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;
```

to:

```
public ArrayAdapter<Product> adapter;
```

Comment: Fortunately works when I delete line with getListAdapter.Why is that?

Comment: it still does not work after your update. My version without getting an adapter inside onClick method works. Why?